# Update LongListSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have in my App LongListSelector and this is how i set the item source:

```
historylist.ItemsSource = new List<VideoItem>(historyRep.historyArray);
```

Now if an item deleted from the array ,there is a new item that added or any item that edited i call this method again to refresh the ItemSource:

```
historylist.ItemsSource = new List<VideoItem>(historyRep.historyArray);
```

But now i noticed that this method made some problem and i want to know if this is the good way to Refresh\Update a LongListSelector??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi This is'nt a good way at all. You should use MVVM pattern ,and assign ItemsSource through xaml. But if you want it done use **ObservableCollection** instead of List.I hope this will help.

Comment: What is the different between list to ObservableCollection?

Comment: ObservableCollection has event collection changed event which is fired everytime you make change in collection and this change is reflected on UI as it fires NotifyPropertyChanged event , but if you will use List then you will have to notify explicitly to update the UI.However if you not making any use of binding you can use UpdateLayOut method.